# How to Properly Use +cache function in Stylus

Tags: mixins, stylus

I am trying to create a mixin using variables and the cache function. It works fine, except for one problem. See sample code below and then I'll explain the problem.

First, here is the mixin (simplified for reasons of space, but in essence this is how it works):

```
mixin($type = apples,
  $color = blue,
  $font-size = 12px,
  $margin = 10px,
  $padding = 20px,
  $border-radius = 30px
  )

if $type == apples
    $color = red

if $type == oranges
    // code
if $type == peas
    // code

+cache('color' + $color)
    color $color     
+cache('font-size' + $font-size)
   font-size $font-size
+cache('margin' + $margin)       
    margin: $margin  
+cache('padding' + $padding)       
    padding: $padding
+cache('border-radius' + $border-radius)       
    border-radius: $border-radius           


.one
    mixin($font-size: 13px)

.two
    mixin($type: oranges)


.three
    mixin($type: peas)
```

This outputs the following code:

```
.one {
  color: #f00;
}
.one {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  margin: 10px;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  padding: 20px;
}
.one,
.two,
.three {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.two,
.three {
  color: #00f;
}
.two,
.three {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

The problem with this method is that the selectors are being unnecessarily repeated. We could easily combine classes one, two and three together for margin, padding and border-radius and classes two and three together for color and font-size.

So let's try another tact for +cache:

```
+cache(
    'color' + $color,
    'font-size' + $font-size,
    'margin' + $margin,
    'padding' + $padding,
    'border-radius' + $border-radius
    )
    color $color     
    font-size $font-size       
    margin: $margin
    padding: $padding
    border-radius: $border-radius
```

This outputs the following code:

```
.one {
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.two,
.three {
  color: #00f;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Now we are unnecessarily outputting properties. margin, padding and border-radius are each mentioned twice.

What I want is a method that will produce the following result:

```
.one,
.two,
.three {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.one {
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 13px
}

.two,
  color:  #00f;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. As it stands this is the best you will get with `+cache`. Although, to make things a bit more readable you can use `+cache(arguments)` like I have done bellow.

```stylus
mixin($type = apples,
$color = blue,
$font-size = 12px,
$margin = 10px,
$padding = 20px,
$border-radius = 30px
)

  +cache(arguments)

    if $type == apples
      $color = red
    if $type == oranges
      // code
    if $type == peas
      // code

    color $color
    font-size $font-size
    margin: $margin
    padding: $padding
    border-radius: $border-radius
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSS minifier should do what you want.  For example, cssnano reduces your original, verbose CSS down to the following (I added whitespace for readability):

```
.one{
    color:red;
    font-size:13px
}
.one,.three,.two{
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:30px
}
.three,.two{
    color:#00f;
    font-size:12px
}
```

[Here is the code in action.](https://tonicdev.com/cspotcode/cssnano-example)